# Receive email on heroku app

Tags: domain-name-system, email, godaddy, heroku

Is it possible to receive domain email at Heroku, and have you domain pointed to the correct place?

For example, I want to receive email at addesses@mydomain.com, and I also want to have my DNS CNAME/A records pointed correctly.

Now as I understand, Heroku does not support traditional DNS records, but I **can** use a service like ZerigoDNS or DNSimple to manage my domain traffic and point that to heroku?

Can someone please help explain how I can have a domain that points to Heroku when I type it in a url bar, **and** also receives email at the destination of the original registrar (godaddy.com)?

Answer (score 0):

Heroku doesn't support receiving email directly to your application, and you can't really run an SMTP server on Heroku anyway. You'll need to use a third party addon such as CloudMailin or Sendgrid.